# Are the primes compressible?

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-complexity

Take a list of the first $n$ primes $P_n=\{2,3,5,7,11,\ldots\}$ and convert the sequence into a binary string

$$S_n = 101110111\ldots$$

Compress the string with your favorite compression algorithm (the details don't matter) and let the size of the string after compression be $C(S_n)$. Compare this to the average over permutations $\pi$ of the string $\left < C(\pi S_n) \right >$, or random strings of 0, or 1 of the same length $C(R_N)$. Why does it seem to be true that

$$
C(S_n) < \left < C(\pi S_n) \right > \approx C(R_N)
$$

implying that primes are compressible!

For example, when $N=2^{21}$, using `zlib` as a compression algorithm and average over 20 trials:

$$
\frac{C(S_n)}{\left < C(\pi S_n) \right >} \approx .761
$$

What is this "redundant data"?

Comment: They can be compressed infinitely more if you allow your compressed data to be a program.   By that I mean, the Huffman prize allows a program to compress data, and specifically encourages it, so why not here? And in this case we know the shortest program is roughly a string holding a < 50 line Python code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that
storage of primes can be compressed
by an arbitrary amount,
though the storage needed
is exponential in the compression factor.

Note:
This has been corrected and been made more precise.

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime
(with $p_1 = 2$),
and let
$P_n$ be the product of the first $n$ primes,
so that
$P_1 = 2, P_2 = 6,
P_3 = 30, P_4 = 210$.

If we do a
sieve of Eratosthenes,
sieving out multiples of the
first $n$ primes,
all that are left
are the first $n$ primes
and the numbers
relatively prime to
$P_n$.

For example,
for $n=2$,
the numbers left are $2, 3$,
and the forms
$6m+1$ and $6m+5$.
For $n=3$,
the numbers left
are $2, 3, 5$
and the forms
$30m+1,7,11,13,17,19,23,$ and $29$.

For general $n$,
the numbers remaining
are of the form
$P_nm+q_i$,
where the $q_i$
are the numbers from $1$ to
$P_n-1$ relatively prime to $P_n$.

To illustrate,
I will use the case $n=3$.

Each block of 30 numbers
in a range
$30m+1$ to $30m+29$
can have as most $8$
primes as shown above.
Therefore,
only one bit is needed 
for each of these $8$ possibilities,
to indicate whether or not
that value is actually prime.
Therefore,
storage of primes can be compressed
by a factor of
$\frac{8}{30} \approx 0.267$.

Here is what happens for
general $n$.

The $P_n$ values
in the range from
$mP_n$ to
$(m+1)P_n-1$
are compressed to
$\phi(P_n)$ bits,
where $\phi(m)$ is Eu;er's phi function
(though he lets me use it)
that counts the 
number of integers
from $1$ to $m$
relatively prime to $m$.

Since $\phi(P_n)
= \prod_{i=1}^n (p_i-1)
$,
the compression factor is
$\dfrac{\phi(P_n)}{P_n}
=\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\dfrac1{p_i})
$.
Since this goes to zero
(because
$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac1{p_i}
\sim \ln \ln n
$ - this is Merten's theorem),
the amount of compression
can be arbitrarily large,
though about
$e^n/n$ bits are needed.

To see this,
by one of the corollaries 
of the prime number theorem,
$P_n \sim e^n$, 
and
$\dfrac{\phi(P_n)}{P_n}
=\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\dfrac1{p_i})
\approx e^{-\ln \ln n}
= 1/\ln n
$.
Therefore,
each block of
$P_n$ values
can be represented by
about $\frac{P_n}{n}$
bits.

Therefore, using a sieve
with the first $n$ primes
and the numbers
relatively prime to $P_n$
can compress the primes
by about a factor of $n$.

Therefore the primes can be compressed by
an arbitrary amount,
though the amount of storage needed
is exponential in $n$.

A number of years ago,
I used this idea
with $n=4$,
so I got a compression of
$\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 6}{2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}
=\frac{8}{35}
$.

Comment: Ah I think I see now, despite the representation (e.g. the variants purposed by Ted) a compression algorithm that relies on a block scheme (like `zlib`) will naturally fall into a length commensurate with the block. Nice insight - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Primes are always odd, so the last bit is always 1 (except for the initial prime 2, of course).  So there is definitely some redundancy.

Another consideration is that your description scheme (listing all the bits of every number) is not optimal.  To describe *any* subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ takes at most $n$ bits, since there are $2^n$ such subsets.  We just have one bit corresponding to each number telling us whether that number is in or out of the subset.

For the particular subset you are considering (the primes), under the description scheme you are using (listing the bits in succession), there are about $\frac{n}{\ln n}$ elements (Prime Number Theorem), and each one has about $\log_2{n}$ bits.  So the number of bits in your description is approximately $\frac{n}{\ln n}(\log_2{n}) = n (\log_2{e})\approx 1.44 n.$

Comment: Just tested this idea by removing the last bit of each prime numbers binary representation and the ratio is still ~.80, so this doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: See edits for another consideration, probably has much greater effect than the 1 bits at the end.

Comment: every prime also starts with a $1$, so the first bit is also always $1$.

Comment: @Ted I've reran the results with the more efficient representation you've suggested. In this case we _still_ have the same ~80% ratio between the prime sequence and the permuted sequence, but now both sequences compress far better than the random sequence (presumably due to the fact that there are more 0's than 1's). So I really appreciate the effort, but neither explanation describes why the prime sequence compresses over a permutation of the same sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The first `23,163,298` primes can be considered compression-friendly. It is the maximum number of primes for which every gap between them is <= `255`, i.e. fits into a single byte. So for those primes, you can use just a single byte per prime, storing the gap, rather than the actual prime as `number`, which consumes `8` bytes. This way, you end up using `8` times less memory.

I used this useful fact in [my solution](https://github.com/vitaly-t/prime-lib/blob/main/src/cache-primes.ts) for caching primes that way.

**UPDATE**

This can be extended even further, to `303,371,455,241` - first prime with gap > `511`, by taking advantage of the fact that all prime gaps are even numbers (except between 2 and 3), and so we can use bit `0` for storing bit `8`, which in turn doubles the supported gap to `511`, and thus increasing the range of primes significantly, to `303,371,455,241`.

I implemented the complete 511 compression solution [in my library](https://github.com/vitaly-t/prime-lib/blob/main/src/cache-primes.ts).